# Outlook 2013 add in. Getting additional information from outlook item, and modifying text context menu in mail body

Tags: c#, contextmenu, outlook-2013, mailitem

I am creating add in for outlook, and I need to get information from selected mail, like 'from' and 'to', but outlook item i work with does not have those properties, and I cannot cast outlook item to interop mail item.

How would I retrieve that info?

Also, I cannot find how to add an item to mail body context menu:
[mail body context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txCeB.png)

I need to add and option in that menu to capture the text user selected in the body of the mail.

Which brings us to my third question, which is how to actually get the selection that user made.

**EDIT:**
Sample code I use to add an option to folder context menu:

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuFolder">
  <button id="MyContextMenuFolder"
          label="ContextMenuFolder"
          onAction="OnMyButtonClick" />
```

And for selected item context menu:

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuMailItem">
  <button id="MyContextMenuMailItem"
          label="ContextMenuMailItem"
          onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
```

I need a same thing in mail body context menu, but I cannot find the idMso of it, fluent UI documentation is very confusing, and I cannot find what I'm looking for there, and I also have no idea if that is the right approach.

Also, this is where I get the selected item (mail):

```
public void OnMyButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;
            if (control.Context is Outlook.Selection)
            {
                msg = "Context=Selection" + "\n";
                Outlook.Selection selection =
                    control.Context as Outlook.Selection;
                if (selection.Count == 1)
                {
                    var olItem =
                        new OutlookItem(selection[1]);
                    msg = msg + olItem.Subject
                        + "\n" + olItem.LastModificationTime;
                }
            }
        }
```

But that OutlookItem does not hold the information I need, is it possible to cast it to MailItem object, or extract more information from it somehow?

Thanks!

P.S. I wanted to post more images, of what I am talking about, but the site doesn't allow me because I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: The reason I did not post more details, images and whatnot, is because site does not allow me (to do many things) because of lack of site reputation, and I do not have the time to build the reputation, because I need help yesterday, not in a week, or two.
So, I added some more information to the post, as much as stack overflow allowed me to.